# How to hide domain name before path?

Tags: wordpress, function, .htaccess, woocommerce, hook

**I was looking for something new for wordpress, I was trying to find all the paid and free plugins but there is no way to hide the domain name in the path.**

**I would like to ask if Wordpress can do this?**

Can you help me with something to get url like in the picture ???

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is a local URL, so they have to be stored locally on your machine and loaded in by a file located on your machine.

Comment: OK, thank you.
I will remove the url and paste it into the head tag so that I can do so.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this correctly than just do what the image says. It isn't that hard. I did it countless times. If you mean like how to hide domain names in the link than refer to [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) and scroll down and go to the "external" tutorial area. And if you mean like in javascript than refer to [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp) and go to the external part of the page. If this didn't help you or I misunderstood than please put more information.

Comment: Thanking you, but I'm in need of something for the whole css link, js wordpress.